# Approximation property of integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Q44. Let $f$ be integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. Establish the following three approximation properties.

(i )There is a simple function $\eta$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which has finite support and $\int_\mathbb{R}|f-\eta|<\epsilon$.

(ii) There is a step function s on $\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes outside a closed, bounded interval and
$\int_\mathbb{R} |f - s| < \epsilon.$

(iii) There is a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes outside a bounded set and

### $\int_\mathbb{R}|f - g| < \epsilon.$

I am good with (i), but I am having some trouble with proving (ii),(iii), so I would appreciate any thought or hints about them, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step (i) follows easily from the Simple Approximation Lemma discussed in virtually every book on Lebesgue measure and integration.

Once you find the step function $s$ in (ii), it is easy to approximate the step function with a continuous function $g$ for (iii) by a straightforward piecewise linear construction.

The difficult part is finding a step function $s$ that approximates the simple function $\eta$ such that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f - s| \leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f - \eta| + \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\eta - s| < \epsilon$$

Here is a sketch of the proof.

Let $E = \text{supp }(\eta)$. It is enough to prove that for a characteristic function $\chi_A$ on a measurable set $A \subset E$, there is a step function $\phi$ such that $\int_E| \chi_A - \phi| < \epsilon$. For any $\delta > 0$, there is an open set $O$ containing $A$ with $m(O \setminus A) < \delta$. As an open set $O$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals

$$O = \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty(a_j,b_j),$$

we have

$$m(O) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty(b_j-a_j) < m(A) + \delta$$

Construct $\phi$ as the characteristic function of a finite union of a sufficiently large number of the intervals $(a_1,b_1), \ldots ,(a_m,b_m)$. This is a step function with the desired properties.

Comment: What does $E=supp (\eta)$ mean , did u mean $m(E)$?

Comment: $E$ is the support of the simple function $\eta$. The simple function is zero outside of this set and from (I) it must be finite. By $m(E)$ I mean the Lebesgue measure of the set $E$.

Comment: Could you give a hint about proving iii?

Comment: I can add more to finish.  Up to that last part the proof is complete assuming you know that any measurable set is contained in an open set that is arbitrarily close in measure ( a standard theorem) and any open set is a union of countably many disjoint open intervals (another well known result). I assume you are OK with that part.

Comment: Sorry. I see you are asking about part 3.

Comment: Say we have the step function $s$ which equals $0$ on $[0,1/2)$ and $1$ on $[1/2,1]$.  We have $\int_0^1 s = 1/2$.  Now construct the continuous function $g$ which equals $0$ on the interval $[0,1/2-2\epsilon]$, has a graph as a straight line joining the point $(1/2- 2\epsilon,0)$ to the point $(1/2,1)$, and then just takes the value $1$ on the interval $[1/2,1]$. Then $\int_0^1 g = 1/2 + $ the area of a triangle of height $1$ and base $2\epsilon$ -- which equals $1/2 + \epsilon$.  Thus $\int_0^1(g - s) = \epsilon$.

Comment: But how does that $g$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ , you dont define it on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In the problem it asks for a continuous function that vanishes out side a bounded set.  Using the linear construction you approximate the step function on a closed bounded interval where it is defined and then extend it continuously so it goes smoothly to zero, but with a very small contribution to the integral.  Just draw a picture and you will get the idea.

Comment: Man, I really respect your brain, appreciate your cooperation. and THANK YOU.

Comment: @Ahmed:  You're welcome.  Part (ii) is still a bit messy to complete -- at least the way I know. I think you could ask just about this part in another question.  Maybe someone knows an easier way, or when I have the time I'll finish what I started.